# Adding Common instance of UIView at zero index of UITableView does not show

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

The structure of my classes is as fellow

- I have a main view controller, let say MainVC;
- Four different view controllers, say vc1, vc2,vc3 and vc4; Each vc has its own UITableView;
- MainVC displays these VCs as subView;
- A sub class of UIView, say headerVC, which returns me a header view which need to show as banner over each table in VCs; This view contains the buttons which switches the Vcs on MainVC;

Now when I run MainVC, it loads the view of VC1 (which has a tableView) and then VC1 adds the headerView at first row of its tableView; When I press any button over headerView, the MainVC toggles the VCs as per selection; Eech VC adds the headerView at first row of its tableView;

Its all works well, but when I navigate away to another tabbar item and comeback, the headerView disappears from selected VC's table; Rest of the rows displays as it is, but header view goes aways; When I scroll the tableView up/down the headerView (in first row) appears again; I'm not getting the reason why it behaving like this;

I tried to put headerView in both tableView's header and section's header but it didn't appear at all; By this approach atleast header view is displaying and working well, but now when I change the tab and come back, only the first row (which contais the header view) disappear;

any clue??

Answer (score 0):

Remove this headerview from row of TableView and add as a static view to the VC, if you want it to move it with the tableView, you can do it via this code

```
float scrollStartPositionY;
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView     {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>=scrollStartPositionY)
        header.hidden=YES;
    else
        header.hidden=FALSE;

header.frame =CGRectMake(header.frame.origin.x,TableView.frame.origin.y TableView.contentOffset.y-    header.frame.size.height,   header.frame.size.width,header.frame.size.height) ;
}

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    scrollStartPositionY=scrollView.contentOffset.y+5;
}
```